# How to use QImage and mousetracking event at the same time in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I am starting to use Qt and I am trying to do an application that uses mouseEvents on a picture QImage. Since I know that QImage is part of QPaintDevice and mouseEvents is part of QWidgets, I don't know how to use both on the same class or even if it would require me to make two independent widgets and overlap them on top of each other. I tried with pixmap, but it is not the best choice since I need pixel manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate mouse position/events in a QWidget. Draw the image on that QWidget either in a paintEvent or simply by placing QLabel with an image without margins/borders on that widget. 
When the image is not scakled, you can calculate the pixel position having the mouse-position within the image.

I think the simplest way to start is to derive your widget from QLabel and overwrite required mouse events. The offset to the pixel is the contentsRect-position